# Is there a practical difference between setting a color to UIColor.clear and nil? - Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a difference between these two statements?

`view.backgroundColor = .clear`

`view.backgroundColor = nil`

I always use the latter, but I mostly see people using `UIColor.clear` whenever they want to make the background clear. Is there actually a difference?

Comment: Using `.clear` will make the code more readable because it describes the intent?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't as the default is transpartent = `clear` see in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622591-backgroundcolor)

```
@NSCopying var backgroundColor: UIColor? { get set }
```

> Changes to this property can be animated. The default value is nil, which results in a transparent background color.